# Find the most suitable sentence for array of tokens

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have the following DataFrame for text mining:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["Anyone who reads Old and Middle English literary texts will be familiar with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfreds jewel embossed on the front cover",
                     "Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or to Aelfric, along with some of those by bishop Wulfstan and much anonymous prose and verse from the pre-Conquest period, are to be found within the Society's three series",
                     "all of the surviving medieval drama, most of the Middle English romances, much religious and secular prose and verse including the English works of John Gower, Thomas Hoccleve and most of Caxton's prints all find their place in the publications",
                     "Without EETS editions, study of medieval English texts would hardly be possible."]})



text
0   Anyone who reads Old and Middle English litera...
1   Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or...
2   all of the surviving medieval drama, most of t...
3   Without EETS editions, study of medieval Engli...
```

And I have lists of tokens:

```
tokens = [['middl engl', 'mid-brown', 'symbol'], ["king", 'anonym', 'series'], ['mediev', 'romance', 'relig'], ['hocclev', 'edit', 'publ']]
```

I'm trying to find the most suitable sentence for each array of tokens from the list **tokens** above.

UPDATE: I was asked to explain my problem in more details.

The problem is that I'm doing it on non-English texts, so it is very problematic to illustrate a bit more of my problem.

I'm looking for some function x which takes as input each element of my **tokens** list and for each element of **tokens** list, it searches for most suitable(maybe in some metric sense) sentences in `df.text`. This is the main idea the output doesn't matter. I just want it to work:)

Comment: Also, can you explain a bit more about your problem, and add an expected output?

Comment: Compute the similarity between sentences and token lists, select the most similar sentence of a token list as its output sentence. Or, a simpler way, counting the occurrence of tokens of each token list in sentences, choose the sentence with maximum occurrence of tokens as the output of the token list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said earlier, this post is just an illustration of my problem. I was solving clustering problem. I used LDA and K-means algorithms to do that. To find the most **suitable sentence** for my tokens list, I used **K-means distance parameter**.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import lda
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import logging
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn import preprocessing 

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["Anyone who reads Old and Middle English literary texts will be familiar with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfreds jewel embossed on the front cover",
                         "Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or to Aelfric, along with some of those by bishop Wulfstan and much anonymous prose and verse from the pre-Conquest period, are to be found within the Society's three series",
                         "all of the surviving medieval drama, most of the Middle English romances, much religious and secular prose and verse including the English works of John Gower, Thomas Hoccleve and most of Caxton's prints all find their place in the publications",
                         "Without EETS editions, study of medieval English texts would hardly be possible."],
                  'tokens':[['middl engl', 'mid-brown', 'symbol'], ["king", 'anonym', 'series'], ['mediev', 'romance', 'relig'], ['hocclev', 'edit', 'publ']]})
df['tokens'] = df.tokens.str.join(',')


vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1, 2))
vz = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['tokens'])

logging.getLogger("lda").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
cvectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, max_features=10000, ngram_range=(1,2))
cvz = cvectorizer.fit_transform(df['tokens'])

n_topics = 4

n_iter = 2000
lda_model = lda.LDA(n_topics=n_topics, n_iter=n_iter)
X_topics = lda_model.fit_transform(cvz)

num_clusters = 4
kmeans_model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++', n_init=1, 
                         init_size=1000, batch_size=1000, verbose=False, max_iter=1000)
kmeans = kmeans_model.fit(vz)
kmeans_clusters = kmeans.predict(vz)
kmeans_distances = kmeans.transform(vz)

X_all  = X_topics
kmeans1 = kmeans_model.fit(X_all)
kmeans_clusters1 = kmeans1.predict(X_all)
kmeans_distances1 = kmeans1.transform(X_all)
d = dict()
l = 1


for i, desc in enumerate(df.text):
    if(i < 3):
        num = 3
        if kmeans_clusters1[i] == num:
            if l > kmeans_distances1[i][kmeans_clusters1[i]]:
                l = kmeans_distances1[i][kmeans_clusters1[i]]  
            d['Cluster' + str(kmeans_clusters1[i])] = "distance:  " + str(l)+ "   "+ df.iloc[i]['text']
            print("Cluster " + str(kmeans_clusters1[i]) + ": " + desc + 
                  "(distance: " + str(kmeans_distances1[i][kmeans_clusters1[i]]) + ")")
            print('---')
print("Cluster " + str(num) + "   " + str(d.get('Cluster' + str(num))))
```

So token with the lowest distance within specific cluster, is the most suitable.